# Email forward to Exchange

Tags: email, cpanel, microsoft, mx

We have a linux Webserver and one of our clients wants us to host their email only, not their site itself. NetworkSolutions manages the domain name. They want us to get their incoming mail and have it sent to their internal Exchange2010 server. Is this doable?

I assume all it would need to be is just the A, CNAME, and MX entries at NS forward to my server IP address, but how would I get it to the exchange server?

Cpanel/WHM based web server.

Comment: Is the exchange server visible on a publicly available IP address?

Comment: The exchange is currently in-house, but will soon be moved to the cloud on a static IP. Change is expected in about 6 months, but she wants something to hold over until then. Someone I know said something about a "catch-all" on exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to forward all email from your server to the exchange server. [This tutorial](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/email/email_forwarding.htm) shows you how. As it relies on domain names you'll need to use the internal name for the exchange server.

Comment: But do I setup those MX records on OUR server as well? The exchange currently is behind the router/firewall so it doesnt have access to the static IP.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your comment carefully and I was answering for the case in 6 months time. I've edited my answer to cover the case until then.